# New can give exceptions other than bad_alloc

Tags: c++, c++11

https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4618/diff.cpp03.language.support

> 18.6.1.1
> Change: operator new may throw exceptions other than std::bad_alloc
>
> Rationale: Consistent application of noexcept.
>
> Effect on original feature: Valid C++ 2003 code that assumes that global operator new only throws std::bad_alloc may execute differently in this International Standard.

According to the given clause, there can be other exceptions than `std::bad_alloc`, any idea what these exceptions are?

Comment: [Read the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new)

Comment: [std::bad_array_new_length](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_array_new_length).